# Como faço para mostrar e selecionar um dos certificados digitais em meu computador

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, certificado-digital

Em meu ambiente de trabalho tenho alguns certificados e preciso selecionar um deles, gostaria de saber via código VN.Net ou C# como faço para aparecer uma lista e eu escolher o certificado digital que preciso, sem precisar atribuir essa lista de certificados em um `combobox`.

Código

```
    Dim ListaCertificados As New List(Of X509Certificate2)()
Private Sub ReloadCerts()

    Dim Store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
    Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly Or OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)

    Dim _certs As X509Certificate2Collection = Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, True).Find(X509FindType.FindByKeyUsage, X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, True)

    For Each Certificado In _certs

        If Certificado.HasPrivateKey Then

            ListaCertificados.Add(Certificado)
            Certificado.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, False)

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Isto te ajuda? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1205295/221800

Comment: De certo modo sim, porém não entendi o `X509Certificate2UI`, ele me apresenta um erro de não estar declarado, mas já foi declarado.

Comment: Provavelmente ele não está visível naquele escopo. Não saberia dizer sem detalhes.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2ui(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Mas continua com o mesmo erro que eu disse...

Comment: Você colocou `using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;`?

Comment: Tanto esse `using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;` quanto esse `using System.Security.Cryptography;`
E nada mesmo erro.
`'X509Certificate2UI' não está declarado. Ele pode ser inacessível devido ao seu nível de proteção.`

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, eu tive que adicionar a referencia System.Security.dll

Comment: Claro, esqueci disto, achei que já estava referenciada. E resolveu tudo? Se eu colocar como resposta, responde sua pergunta?

Comment: Então, isso foi um imprevisto. A resposta de minha pergunta é o seguinte código, que no caso eu consegui o que queria.
`Dim Store As X509Store = New X509Store(StoreName.My,` `StoreLocation.CurrentUser)`
`Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly Or` `OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly)`
`Dim certificateCollection As X509CertificateCollection =` `X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(Store.Certificates,` `"Caption", "Message", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)`

Comment: Poste a resposta você então.

Comment: Não irei postar, pq o mérito foi seu em mostrar o link no primeiro comentário, do que no caso, me ajudou com o que procurava. Agradeço!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6830696/221800) no SO é possível fazer o que deseja. A forma de busca é que tem que ser diferente (aproveitando o código colocado no comentário ficaria assim:

```
Dim certificateCollection As X509CertificateCollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(Store.Certificates, "Caption", "Message", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Certificate.vb).